# Creating 2D colormap with Arrays (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

Hello I wrote a programm to calculate the Bethe–Weizsäcker mass formula. I was able to compute  3 Arrays containg the data for x (Number of neutrons),y(Number of protons) and z(binding energy). Now I want to create a plot as seen here:[image: Bethe–Weizsäcker mass]

Unfortunately I have no idea how to create such an 2D color plot.

Comment: checkout `contourf`.

Comment: It's a combination of a contour plot and a pseudocolor (pcolor) plot.

Comment: `contourf` works with a regular grid on XY, or rectangular grid on XY. But if your data is just a random cloud of points, try `tricontourf`.